# Renaming file and returning new file pointer

Tags: java, file

I have a piece of code where I am retrieving a file from a URL and saving it to temp folder. For my use case, I need the file name to be a specific string say 'filename'.

So far the code I have is,

```
try (AutoDeletingFile fileToUpload = new AutoDeletingFile(pullFile(fileUrl))) {
        fileToUpload.getFile().renameTo(new File(filename));
}
```

But when I use fileToUpload.getName post rename, it still gives me the original file name. Is there a clean way to get the file pointer of the new file while renaming it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `fileToUpload.getFile()` only return value, not the reference. So, to update the actual file, you need to:

```
File file = fileToUpload.getFile();
file.renameTo(new File(filename));
fileToUpload.setFile(file);
```

That and inside the `setFile()`, you replace `File` variable inside `fileToUpload` with the new one.